# Фильтрация массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Необходимо фильтровать массив arr1 по id, которые соответствует `itemIds` в массиве объектов arr2.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: '0',
    title: 'item1'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'item2'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'item3'
  },
];


const arr2 = [{
    itemIds: ['0', '1']
  }
];
```

Comment: фильтровать и? и выбросить?

Comment: @qwabra, и вывести в консоль

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, что вы сами уже попробовали (добавьте код в вопрос), и чем ваша реализация оказалась не подходящей

Comment: `arr1.filter(e1 => arr2.some(e2 => e2.itemIds.includes(e1.id)))` как-то так ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: '0', title: 'item1' },
  { id: '1', title: 'item2' },
  { id: '2', title: 'item3' },
];

var arr2 = [{
  itemIds: ['0', '1'],
  extra: 'abc'
}];

var items = new Map(arr1.map(x => [x.id, x]))

console.log(arr2.map(({ itemIds, ...x }) => ({
  ...x,
  items: itemIds.map(id => items.get(id))
})))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```